# changing certain elements in a 2D array

Tags: matlab

I'm working on an algorithm in Matlab that requires certain elements of a matrix to be updated regularly and looking how best to do this. Here is a description of what i'm trying to achieve:

1. I have a MxN array `A` and 1xN vector `B`.
2. Basically, vector `B` is a logical index that describes which column of `A` that I need to select i.e. `C = A(:,B)`.
3. Unfortunately, logical vector `B` varies depending on some processes. This means the number of columns in `C` is not fixed.
4. Some other processing will use `C` as inputs and produce another array `D` that has the same size as `C` i.e. `size(D) == size(C)`
5. Now, I need to "reshape" `D` so that it has the same size as `A`. The tricky part is those columns in `A` that weren't chosen in #2 above needs to be replaced by `NaN`s. Of course I can do it the crude way of using loops. But I'm looking to do this the Matlab-way i.e. linear or logical indexing, vectorization, etc This is where I got stuck at the moment.

Some examples to make things clearer:

Lets say

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9] 
B = [1 0 1] 
C = A(:,B) = [1 3; 4 6; 7 9]
```

After some processing, I'll get `D = [2 5; 6 7; 3 3]`. Now, I need to "reshape" `D` into the same size as `A` by padding with `NaN` i.e. `D = [2 NaN 5; 6 NaN 7; 3 NaN 3]`.

What I've tried so far,

```
Atmp = NaN(size(A));
Btmp = find(repmat(B,[size(B,1),1]));
Atmp(Btmp) = D(Btmp); %-> error because D is smaller than A.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
fullD = NaN(size(A));
fullD(:, B) = D;
```

Comment: that works well. i knew it must be something really simple like this but i've been cracking/banging my head trying to figure this out. thanks so much.